# Как подключить api TINKOFF оплата на laravel? Как подключить api TINKOFF оплата на laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

Как подключить api TINKOFF оплата на laravel?
С чего начать, я вообще не понимаю как делать, как проверять прошел ли тестовый платеж. Доку читал ничего не понял

Answer (score 0):

Для интеграции оплаты по Tinkoff в Laravel необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

1. **Подготовьте свой проект Laravel.** Убедитесь, что у вас установлена последняя версия Laravel и что в вашем проекте включена поддержка Composer.
2. **Создайте файл конфигурации.** Создайте файл `tinkoff.php` в каталоге `config` вашего проекта. В этом файле вы можете указать следующие параметры:

```php
return [
    'merchant_id' => 'YOUR_MERCHANT_ID',
    'secret_key' => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
    'webhook_secret' => 'YOUR_WEBHOOK_SECRET',
];
```

- `merchant_id` - идентификатор вашего merchant в Tinkoff.
- `secret_key` - секретный ключ вашего merchant в Tinkoff.
- `webhook_secret` - секретный ключ для webhook-сообщений от Tinkoff.

3. **Добавьте зависимости.** Чтобы использовать библиотеку Tinkoff для Laravel, необходимо добавить ее в зависимости вашего проекта. Для этого выполните следующую команду:

```
composer require tinkoff/laravel
```

4. **Инициализируйте библиотеку.** После того, как вы добавили зависимость, необходимо инициализировать библиотеку. Для этого выполните следующую команду:

```php
$app->register(TinkoffServiceProvider::class);
```

5. **Создайте форму оплаты.** Чтобы создать форму оплаты, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```html
<form action="{{ route('pay') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ $amount }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Оплатить">
</form>
```

В этом примере форма отправляет запрос на маршрут `pay`, в котором передается параметр `amount` - сумма платежа.

6. **Обработайте запрос оплаты.** В маршруте `pay` вам необходимо обработать запрос оплаты. Для этого вы можете использовать следующий код:

```php
Route::post('pay', function (Request $request) {
    $amount = $request->input('amount');

    // Создайте объект платежа
    $payment = new TinkoffPayment($amount);

    // Отправьте запрос на оплату
    $response = $payment->pay();

    // Обработайте ответ
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        // Платеж прошел успешно
    } else {
        // Произошла ошибка
    }
});
```

В этом примере код создает объект платежа, отправляет запрос на оплату и обрабатывает ответ.

7. **Подключите webhook.** Чтобы получать уведомления о статусе платежей, необходимо подключить webhook. Для этого выполните следующие шаги:

- Создайте URL webhook-сервера.
- Включите webhook в настройках merchant в Tinkoff.

После того, как вы подключите webhook, Tinkoff будет отправлять вам уведомления о статусе платежей.

Вот пример webhook-сообщения:

```json
{
    "id": "1234567890",
    "status": "succeeded",
    "amount": 1000,
    "currency": "RUB",
    "description": "Оплата заказа №1234567890",
    "created_at": "2023-11-08T12:00:00+03:00",
    "updated_at": "2023-11-08T12:00:00+03:00"
}
```

В этом примере сообщение содержит следующие данные:

- `id` - идентификатор платежа.
- `status` - статус платежа.
- `amount` - сумма платежа.
- `currency` - валюта платежа.
- `description` - описание платежа.
- `created_at` - дата и время создания платежа.
- `updated_at` - дата и время обновления платежа.

Более подробную информацию об интеграции оплаты по Tinkoff в Laravel вы можете найти в документации библиотеки Tinkoff для Laravel.